# Finish Activity via Home Button while AlertDialog.Builder is active

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, activity-finish

I want my app to finish the current activity while a `AlertDialog.Builder` is active by clicking on the Home Button for only one time. Normally it needs two clicks (first click closes dialog, second closes the current activity then).

I've tried to put `finish()` into the `public boolean onKeyDown()` method, but I only get into it within the 2nd click (i.e. when the `AlertDialog.Builder` isn't active anymore).

Any ideas?

PS: My `AlertDialog.Builder` is in the`onCreate(`) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dialog is non-cancelable, it should take you to the home screen on the first press of the home button.  See [`AlertDialog.Builder#setCancelable(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29).

Comment: when the dialog isnt cancelable, pressing on the homebutton does nothing. So the user is forced to press the negativeButton on the dialog an there i can implement finish(). Thats not exactly the workflow i accepted but its a good alternative. thank you :)

Comment: @pebbles Strange... that's not what I'm seeing in my own app.  Then again, I'm using `AlertDialog`s in `DialogFragment`s.

Comment: yeah... maybe ther is another behavior in a DialogFragment. Nevermind, setCancelable(false) is fine for my case - thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

when you pressed Home Button on activity , it calls the OnStop() method

so you must to handle that on your Activity :

```
  @Override
        protected void onStop() {

            super.onStop();
        }
```

so in your case , you can use this :

```
  @Override
        protected void onStop() {

        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);

        }
```

hope helps you ;) 
wish you luck

Comment: I'm sorry to disappoint you, but this doesnt work. onStop() is called when the activity is active (and not the dialog) and i press the Homebutton. In my case its called when i click the homebutton a second time.